# A question about warning that performing k-fold CV with caret

Tags: cross-validation, caret

I am trying to `createFolds` function in `caret` to use k-fold cross-validation in R. But I came across this warning:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In foldVector[which(y == dimnames(numInClass)$y[i])] <- sample(seqVector) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Has anyone come across this before & solved it?

I am using this R code:

```
> flds<-createFolds(dataset,k=5, list=TRUE, returnTrain=FALSE)
```

The data-set includes my response variables that I am going to use with Linear Discriminant Analysis

> str(dataset)

'data.frame':   200 obs. of  162 variables:

$ V2  : Factor w/ 201 levels "6.74361083760967",..: 150 190 108 157 180 7 139 116 175 49 ...

$ V3  : Factor w/ 201 levels "1.88828398539874",..: 114 177 42 155 143 173 144 81 142 117 ...

[list output truncated]

Comment: Could you give as an example of r code for which you get that error? Also, this could be better suited for stack overflow with r tag.

Comment: Could you also give us the output of `str(dataset)`

Comment: dataset should be a vector and not a data.frame

Comment: Thank you. But How can I transform dataset to a vector? I have tried as.vector(dataset) It did not work. I am just learning R programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please rewrite your question and try to better explain what you really want to do.

Comment: You have some factors having more levels than the number of observations... they rather look like a numerical variable